# Iterating through a list in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I have the following text file.

```
[box_1]
show ethernet 
show adjacency
show log
[box_2]
run ethernet 
run adjacency
show log
```

I need to write a robot file, where if it encounters [box_1], it will run,

```
run ethernet 
run adjacency
show log
```

And if it encounters [box_2], it will run the following commands under that.

This is my robot code:

```
${File}=    Get File  Resources\\Source\\textfile.txt
@{list}=    Split to lines  ${File}    
Log    ${list}
${op}=    Get From List ${list}    0    
log    ${op}
${first_line}=    Get Slice From List   ${list}    1
:FOR    ${line}    IN    @{first_line}
\   ${result}=    Run Keyword If    '${op}'=='[${box_1}]' and     run_command    ${line}
\   ${result}=    Run Keyword If    '${op}'=='[${box_2}]' and     run_command    ${line}
```

But its only taking identifying the [box_1] and not going to [box_2]. And there can be multiple number of boxes followed by the commands.
Can someone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain how this relates to Python code.

Comment: @pylang, Robot Framework is a Python application. Which means that if the own DSL can't handle a situation we revert to Python for customization. It is very likely that this is going to be the recommendation here.

Comment: @Addy is the input file format fixed? In Robot Framework we have external variable files that are formatted slightly differently but are much easier to process Robot side. In the [User guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files) there is a specific section on [YAML ](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-file-as-yaml) variable files that I think may be of use here.

Comment: The data shows "show adjacency", but you say you want to "run adjacency". It's not clear what should happen on each loop. Are you wanting to replace "show" with "run", or do you want to run "show adjacency"?

Comment: @A.Kootstra Yes the input format is fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although @Psytho is right, it is not entirely sufficient to solve the issues.

In the below example I've added the required Libraries and a custom keyword to mimic the run command `Operatingsystem` keyword.

In this example I skip the headers and execute the commands. In a similar way you can use the value in `${match[0]}` to learn which header is currently active and use it in your determination what to do.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    String    
Library    Collections
Library    OperatingSystem    

*** Test Cases ***
TC v1
    ${File}=    Get File  textfile.txt
    @{lines}=    Split to lines  ${File}    

    :FOR    ${line}    IN    @{lines}
    \    ${match}  Get Regexp Matches    ${line}    \\[(.*)\\]    1
    \    ${count}  Get Length    ${match}
    \    ${result}  Run Keyword If    ${count} == 0    run_custom_command    ${line}  
TC v2
    @{commands}    Get Commands    box_2    textfile.txt
    :FOR    ${command}    IN    @{commands}
    \    run_custom_command    ${command}    

    @{commands}    Get Commands    box_1    textfile.txt
    :FOR    ${command}    IN    @{commands}
    \    run_custom_command    ${command}       

*** Keywords ***
Run Custom Command
    [Arguments]    ${command}
    Log    Run Command: ${command}
    [return]    SUCCESS

Get Commands
    [Arguments]    ${ENV}    ${filepath}
    ${string}=    Get File            ${filepath}
    ${match}=     Get Regexp Matches  ${string}    \\[${ENV}\\]\\n((.|\\n)*?)(\\[|$)    1
    @{lines}=     Split to lines   ${match[0]}
    [Return]    ${lines}
```

EDIT: Added a second option that relies on just a regular expression.

Comment: Hi @A.Kootstra thanks for the help. But the thing is the run_command is a function defined in python and the commands are restricted to the specific boxes. So suppose if its [box_1], only the commands that are under [box_1] will run.So thats the reason we are putting [box_1] and [box_2].So like run ethernet will run, if getting connected to box_2.

Comment: This makes more sense. However, this brings me back to my original question. Can you alter the format of the config/text file? If it were in a Robot Framwork supported [Variable File](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files) format this would be considerably easier.

Comment: I've altered the answer to include a second option. This uses the regular expression approach to fetch everything between the section header and the next one.

Comment: Thanks so much @A.Kootstra. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You assign `${op}` only once in

`${op}=    Get From List ${list}    0`

and never change it. That is why it is always `[box_1]` and never becomes `[box_2]`. You must moe the assignment into `FOR`-loop and change the rest of code so that the commands between different `box`-es are executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
*** Variables ***
${A}    A
${B}    B
${C}    c
*** Keywords ***
Test
    Log To Console    ${A}
    Log To Console    ${B}
    Log To Console    ${C}
    [Return]    ${A}    ${B}    ${C}    

*** Test Cases ***
Test1
    ${A0}    ${B0}    ${C0}    Test
    Log To Console    ${A0}
    Log To Console    ${B0}
    Log To Console    ${C0}


When you are calling the keyword in the test case u can assign the return variables as above.`
```